# Can we assign value to a structure variable itself?( if it's a pointer variable too)?

Tags: c, pointers, stack, structure

I have limited knowledge of structure in c, and what I know is that you can assign value to members of structure not to structure itself. So my main question is that is it allowed to assign value to the structure variable itself if it's a pointer variable too?
ex : top = p;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct stack
{
    int no;
    struct stack *prev;

} *top = NULL;
typedef struct stack st;
void push();
void push()
{
    st *p;
    p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    printf("\nEnter the value : ");
    scanf("%d", &p->no);
    p->prev = top;
    top = p;

}
```

Comment: The variables you seem to be talking about have *pointer* type, not structure type (more specifically, pointer-to-structure type, but that's still a pointer type, not a structure type).

Comment: But overall, yes, any modifiable lvalue can be assigned a value of compatible type.  Including lvalues of structure type.

Comment: @pmg: “Compatible” has a technical meaning in the C standard, and `void *` is not compatible with other pointer types. It is automatically convertible to other types of pointers to objects (in the sense the constraints for assignment allow it without requiring a diagnostic), although the reverse is true only when no top-level qualifiers are present. “Compatible” largely means two types can be completed to be the same type, which is not true for `void *` with other pointer types. The technical meaning is important in the standard, so please do not muddle it by using it for a different meaning.

Comment: Right @EricPostpischil, thank you. 2nd version of my comment: Do not cast the return value of `malloc()` ... to either the correct type or an "incorrect type". `malloc()` returns a pointer to `void` which is directly assignable, with no cast required, to a pointer to any thing.

Answer (score 1):

`top` has type `struct stack *`, so it's perfectly fine to assign it the value of another variable with that type, in this case `p`.

And you can actually assign an entire struct at once.  For example:

```
struct s {
   int a;
   int b;
};

int main()
{
    struct s x,y;
    x.a = 2;
    x.b = 3;
    y = x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so assigning y = x will actually assign the value of x.a and x.b to y.a and y.b right sir? Is that the same is happening in top = p?

Comment: @NishuPatel No, it's not the same. `top` and `p` are just pointers.  They contain the address of a `struct stack`.  `p` is assigned the address of allocated memory containing one of these structs, and `top = p` simply assigns that pointer value to `top`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign directly to a structure:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack
{
    int no;
    struct stack *prev;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct stack *top = malloc(sizeof *top);
    if (top)
    {
        // use top
        *top = (struct stack){42, NULL}; // assign to *top directly
        // ...
        free(top);
    }
    return 0;
}
```